Does running a mpirun in two nodes require passwordless SSH access?
I am trying to run mpirun in two nodes.
from node11
$mpirun -np 2 -host localhost,compute12 hostname
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
At least one of the requested hosts is not included in the current
allocation.

   Missing requested host: compute12

Please check your allocation or your request.
--------------------------------------------------------------------------]

From the login node it gets frozen and when I do ctrl-C I get
me@compute12's password:
Permission denied, please try again
me@compute12's password:
Permission denied, please try again(publickey,gssapi-keyex,gssapi-with-mic,password).

So the conclusion I get is that in Node 11, it is not even trying since node 12 is not in its allocation
(Node 11)
$ scontrol show hostname
Node-11

while in the login node it is trying to connect but trying to get the password (although not showing me)
For some reason though
(Login node)
$ scontrol show hostname
scontrol: error: host list is empty

Does running mpirun requires that the involved nodes are set with passwordless SSH access?

It does, because it runs the ssh clients in a way that they cannot really prompt for password; they are run in parallel and end up fighting over control of the terminal (which they don't have in the first place) during the attempt to show the password prompt.
But if you have a cluster, where all machines are equal, then some form of passwordless SSH access is something you ought to already have anyway. Your ssh output suggests that the servers offer Kerberos (gssapi-with-mic), which means you should be able to kinit on the login node to get credentials. (On the other hand, if you manage this cluster, then the rarely-used Hostbased authentication mode may be very convenient to set up, since it does not require per-user keypairs but relies on trust between whole hosts.)
Although technically speaking, it's not the authentication that needs to be passwordless, but the ssh command specifically – so if you insist on unique passwords for each cluster node, then you can set up OpenSSH's "connection multiplexing" to pre-connect to each server (using the ControlPath option), enter the passwords for each of your nodes, and leave those connections parked so that when mpirun calls ssh again, it will just re-use the same (already authenticated) connection.
